# pattern for string in quotes with shielding in lexer

Tags: haskell, lexer

I'm trying to parse any symbols in doulbe quotes, but I don't know how to include supporting special symbols and shielding
I can do that

```
$anybq=[^"]
\"$anybq*\"                        { \s -> TText (pack (init (tail s)))     }
```

but I want to support shielding:
strings like "sdfsfd"dsfsdfs"
and special symbols
strings like "sdfsfd\ndsfsdfs"

Comment: You can't embed quotes in a quotes string without ambiguity. Is `"foo"bar"baz"` two quoted strings surrounding `bar`, or a single quoted string containing two `"` characters?

Comment: @chepner 
I want to get error in this strnig. But I want to parse "foo\"bar\"baz"

Comment: If you are using a library to build your parser, it probably has a way to handle escaped characters. If you are building this from scratch, you are going to have to look for and handle an escape character yourself.